# How do I send email alerts based on custom formula fields or past due dates?

Tags: process-builder, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

How do I create a process that will auto-send an email alert when a record is 10, 20 or 30 days passed another date field?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Please take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) & look in the Help Center - especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where it states, _"Questions that ask for the community to write code or provide step-by-step instructions for implementation...are likely to be closed."_ This site exists to _help_ you. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/358577/edit) your question to include what you have tried and how it is not working (e.g., exact errors, issues).

Comment: You'll want to search for scheduled actions or time-based actions for workflow / process builder / Flow.

Answer (score 1):

you will want to have some kind of scheduled automation, flows,process builder etc

[workflow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&id=sf.workflow_time_dependent.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=Time%2Ddependent%20actions%20are%20executed,still%20meets%20the%20rule%20criteria.)

[flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_trigger_schedule.htm&type=5)

Or if you are a dev you can write a batch that checks how many days it has been for the records and fires the email